# Close a window of another application in .NET

Tags: .net, window

I would like to close a window of an external application, but only a window, not the whole application. For example, I have the following application (Resource-Manager) with two open windows:

[image]

I would like to close the window "Generate vb-code", but let "Resource-Manager" open and the application running.

Is there any way to do this in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to close the 'Generate vb-code' window from another .Net application. You should be able to achieve this via [UIAutomation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753107(v=vs.110).aspx).

Using this framework you can access the application and get a handle on the open windows and close them.

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744877%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains the route of finding a UI element.

**Edit Added Code example**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AutomationElement mainWindow = AutomationElement.RootElement;

        var winCollection = mainWindow.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);

        foreach (AutomationElement element in winCollection)
        {
            if (element.Current.Name == "Generate vb-code")
            {
                var closeButton = element.FindDescendentByIdPath(new[] { "TitleBar", "Close" });
                if (closeButton != null)
                    closeButton.GetInvokePattern().Invoke();
            }
        }
    }

}

public static class AutomationExtensions
{
    public static void EnsureElementIsScrolledIntoView(this AutomationElement element)
    {
        if (!element.Current.IsOffscreen)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!(bool)element.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.IsScrollItemPatternAvailableProperty))
        {
            return;
        }

        var scrollItemPattern = element.GetScrollItemPattern();
        scrollItemPattern.ScrollIntoView();
    }

    public static AutomationElement FindDescendentByConditionPath(this AutomationElement element, IEnumerable<Condition> conditionPath)
    {
        if (!conditionPath.Any())
        {
            return element;
        }

        var result = conditionPath.Aggregate(
            element,
            (parentElement, nextCondition) => parentElement == null
                                                  ? null
                                                  : parentElement.FindChildByCondition(nextCondition));

        return result;
    }

    public static AutomationElement FindDescendentByIdPath(this AutomationElement element, IEnumerable<string> idPath)
    {
        var conditionPath = CreateConditionPathForPropertyValues(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, idPath.Cast<object>());

        return FindDescendentByConditionPath(element, conditionPath);
    }

    public static AutomationElement FindDescendentByNamePath(this AutomationElement element, IEnumerable<string> namePath)
    {
        var conditionPath = CreateConditionPathForPropertyValues(AutomationElement.NameProperty, namePath.Cast<object>());

        return FindDescendentByConditionPath(element, conditionPath);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Condition> CreateConditionPathForPropertyValues(AutomationProperty property, IEnumerable<object> values)
    {
        var conditions = values.Select(value => new PropertyCondition(property, value));

        return conditions.Cast<Condition>();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the first child of the element that has a descendant matching the condition path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">The element.</param>
    /// <param name="conditionPath">The condition path.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static AutomationElement FindFirstChildHavingDescendantWhere(this AutomationElement element, IEnumerable<Condition> conditionPath)
    {
        return
            element.FindFirstChildHavingDescendantWhere(
                child => child.FindDescendentByConditionPath(conditionPath) != null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the first child of the element that has a descendant matching the condition path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">The element.</param>
    /// <param name="conditionPath">The condition path.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static AutomationElement FindFirstChildHavingDescendantWhere(this AutomationElement element, Func<AutomationElement, bool> condition)
    {
        var children = element.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);

        foreach (AutomationElement child in children)
        {
            if (condition(child))
            {
                return child;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static AutomationElement FindChildById(this AutomationElement element, string automationId)
    {
        var result = element.FindChildByCondition(
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, automationId));

        return result;
    }

    public static AutomationElement FindChildByName(this AutomationElement element, string name)
    {
        var result = element.FindChildByCondition(
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, name));

        return result;
    }

    public static AutomationElement FindChildByClass(this AutomationElement element, string className)
    {
        var result = element.FindChildByCondition(
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, className));

        return result;
    }

    public static AutomationElement FindChildByProcessId(this AutomationElement element, int processId)
    {
        var result = element.FindChildByCondition(
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, processId));

        return result;
    }

    public static AutomationElement FindChildByControlType(this AutomationElement element, ControlType controlType)
    {
        var result = element.FindChildByCondition(
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, controlType));

        return result;
    }

    public static AutomationElement FindChildByCondition(this AutomationElement element, Condition condition)
    {
        var result = element.FindFirst(
            TreeScope.Children,
            condition);

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the child text block of an element.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element">The element.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static AutomationElement FindChildTextBlock(this AutomationElement element)
    {
        var child = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetFirstChild(element);

        if (child != null && child.Current.ControlType == ControlType.Text)
        {
            return child;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public static class PatternExtensions
{
    public static string GetValue(this AutomationElement element)
    {
        var pattern = element.GetPattern<ValuePattern>(ValuePattern.Pattern);

        return pattern.Current.Value;
    }

    public static void SetValue(this AutomationElement element, string value)
    {
        var pattern = element.GetPattern<ValuePattern>(ValuePattern.Pattern);

        pattern.SetValue(value);
    }

    public static ScrollItemPattern GetScrollItemPattern(this AutomationElement element)
    {
        return element.GetPattern<ScrollItemPattern>(ScrollItemPattern.Pattern);
    }

    public static InvokePattern GetInvokePattern(this AutomationElement element)
    {
        return element.GetPattern<InvokePattern>(InvokePattern.Pattern);
    }

    public static SelectionItemPattern GetSelectionItemPattern(this AutomationElement element)
    {
        return element.GetPattern<SelectionItemPattern>(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern);
    }

    public static SelectionPattern GetSelectionPattern(this AutomationElement element)
    {
        return element.GetPattern<SelectionPattern>(SelectionPattern.Pattern);
    }

    public static TogglePattern GetTogglePattern(this AutomationElement element)
    {
        return element.GetPattern<TogglePattern>(TogglePattern.Pattern);
    }

    public static WindowPattern GetWindowPattern(this AutomationElement element)
    {
        return element.GetPattern<WindowPattern>(WindowPattern.Pattern);
    }

    public static T GetPattern<T>(this AutomationElement element, AutomationPattern pattern) where T : class
    {
        var patternObject = element.GetCurrentPattern(pattern);

        return patternObject as T;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. It finds the close button and everything works fine till line closeButton.GetInvokePattern().Invoke(). It goes through without error but form doesn't close. Do you have any idea why? Thank you again.

Comment: Hi @gogcam, not sure on why it wouldn't work. Is the resource manager, your application? if so is there any code that would prevent the close button from working? Is there another button on that form that could be used to close the form?